# Not able to locate element when running chrome in headless mode

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

@DebanjanB - Hello. I have automated the download of a website using selenium chrome driver. However when I run chrome in headless mode, it is not able to locate the checkbox which is to be clicked to download the file. Can you help me figure out this problem?

Below is my code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object selen extends App{

  val chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
  chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless")
  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)
  val driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)

  driver.get("url")

  driver.findElement(By.id("isc_S")).sendKeys("Username")
  driver.findElement(By.id("isc_V")).sendKeys("Password")
  driver.findElement(By.id("isc_Z")).click
  println("Logged in")

  driver.manage.window.maximize
  Thread.sleep(5000);

  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#isc_36 > table > tbody > tr > td")).click()
  println("clicked Dashboard")
  Thread.sleep(5000);

  var count = 1

  for (i <- 1 to 9) {
    for (j <- 1 to 5) {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"isc_5Ptable\"]/tbody/tr[" + count + "]/td[1]/div/span")).click()
      driver.findElement(By.id("isc_64")).click()
      Thread.sleep(4000)
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"isc_5Ptable\"]/tbody/tr[" + count + "]/td[1]/div/span")).click()
      count+=1
    }

    var count2 = 10
    while(count2 > 0)
    {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"isc_5Q\"]/img[3]")).click()
      count2 -= 1
    }
  }
  driver.close()
}
```

Below is the html of the checkbox which is not being located in headless chrome driver:

span style="display:inline-block;background-size:100% 100%;background-image:url("https://ford-ddlive.clifford-thames.com/datadistribution/sc/skins/ford/images/DynamicForm/unchecked.png");width:13px;height:13px;vertical-align:text-top;margin-left:2px;margin-right:2px" eventpart="valueicon">

Comment: @MateMrše - I have updated it.

Comment: @AnandNautiyal Only the `<span>` may not be enough and you need to usdate the question with some more of the outerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using explicit wait (FluentWait) instead of sleep() and instead of findElement()

Comment: FluentWait looks suitable, but the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) illustrates using it _with_ `findElement` not _instead of_ it. Including code example of what you mean would help.

Comment: Right, FluentWait  is like while(timeout || elementIsFound) { findElement()}. If element is not found right away it waits a little and repeats findElement() several times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your element is not in the viewport, because headless chrome might have a different resolution than your normal workspace.

So, try maximizing the headless chrome by adding `chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximised")` after `chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless")` line.